# How do i insert a hidden row into a table with an onclick, continuously in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the html and jquery code for the function. It initializes the first row, so now i would like to call the hidden row as i click the button, as many times as i can with that same button. Here's my code so far

```js
<!-- Jquery button click function -->
    $(function() {
        $('button').click(function() {
            $('#other_tr').show()
            var clone =  $('#other_tr').clone;
            $('#first_tr').after(clone)
        })
    });
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr id="first_tr">
       <th>Unit price</th>
       <th>Discount</th>
       <th>Total</th>
   </tr>
            
            <!-- hidden row -->
            <tr id="other_tr" style="display: none;">
       <th>Unit price</th>
       <th>Discount</th>
       <th>Total</th>
   </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <button>Fetch Row</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after, although I would suggest creating an empty `tbody` and appending the new rows to that.

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var clone = $('#other_tr').clone();
    $('table thead').append(clone);
    clone.show();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr id="first_tr">
      <th>Unit price</th>
      <th>Discount</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>

    <!-- hidden row -->
    <tr id="other_tr" style="display: none;">
      <th>Unit price</th>
      <th>Discount</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<button>Fetch Row</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<!-- Jquery button click function -->
    $(function() {
        $('button').click(function() {
            $('#other_tr').show();
            var clone =  $('#other_tr').clone();
            $('#first_tr').after(clone);
        })
    });
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr id="first_tr">
       <th>Unit price</th>
       <th>Discount</th>
       <th>Total</th>
   </tr>
            
            <!-- hidden row -->
            <tr id="other_tr" style="display: none;">
       <th>Unit price</th>
       <th>Discount</th>
       <th>Total</th>
   </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <button>Fetch Row</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you remove `other_tr` on page load, remove it's id, and store in variable.

Then clone that variable each time

```js
$(function() {

  var $tr = $('#other_tr').detach().show().removeAttr('id');

  $('button').click(function() {
    $('#first_tr').after($tr.clone());
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr id="first_tr">
      <th>Unit price</th>
      <th>Discount</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>

    <!-- hidden row -->
    <tr id="other_tr" style="display: none;">
      <th>Unit price</th>
      <th>Discount</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<button>Fetch Row</button>
```